# Does this function or the vector used by reference leak memory?

Tags: c++, vector, getline, lexical

I am having problems with clearing my pointer maps which root to the use of this method. If i dont use this, all is fine.

I need to convert the desired amount of numbers read from the file to a vector of double.

```
void LoadNumbersFromFile(const std::string fileName, int countToLoad, std::vector<double>& output)
{


    ifstream in("C:\\" + fileName);

    std::string line="0";
    int index = 0;

    if (in.is_open())
    while(getline(in,line))
    {
        output.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<double>(line));
        index++;
        if (index>=countToLoad) 
            break;
    }
    in.close();

}
```

My question is that does this method leak memory ?

If it does, is it fixable or do we have any other alternatives ?

Comment: No it does not leak memory unless you have a bug in your standard library or boost implementation.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But your ToDo list: 1) repeatedly calling `push_back` is not a good thing to do with a `std::vector`. 2) check that the `ifstream` destructor calls `close` if necessary; just in case an exception is thrown in your `while` loop.

Comment: i.e you don't actually need to call `in.close()`. You can remove that line.

Comment: Why would you think there's any memory leak?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't understand your first point. What is the "good" alternative to `push_back` for adding elements to this `std::vector`?

Comment: Call `reserve` if possible.

Comment: @Bathsheba Re 1): and what is the alternative?  His use seems perfectly correct and idiomatic.  Re 2) `ifstream::~ifstream` closes the file, so the `in.close()` in his code is not necessary.  (When outputting, you usually need an explicit `close()` since you need check the status of the stream _after_ closing it.)

Comment: @Bathsheba That's an optimization.  _If_ you have a performance problem, _and_ you know the maximum number of values which will be pushed, then certainly, use `reserve`.  Here, neither of these conditions seem to be met.